# Store tesseract OCR traineddata on S3?

Tags: pdf, heroku, ocr, tesseract

I have an app hosted on Heroku. I seek to extract text from various PDFs. I'm currently using `tesseract` for this.

Since Heroku does not offer that much storage space and the `.traineddata` files are big in size (need to use all of them), is it possible to somehow store the `tessdata` language data on S3? I was not able to find any solution to this yet.

All I could find is that I can define the `--tessdata-dir PATH`, but that's for a directory.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, I'm not sure Heroku is a good fit for your needs if you can't make all the data fit within the heroku slug. Even if you could get it to work, it would be quite a performance hit.

You'd probably be better off setting the Tesseract as an API with it's own server(s), then sending whatever you need to that API from heroku (or moving the entire app over). Depending on the size of the rest of your app and how quickly Tesseract is growing in size, that might just mean Tesseract gets it's own heroku app with absolutely minimal dependencies or might mean moving that part of the app to AWS or something.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did manage to find some solutions, though they are not entirely straightforward. One solution is to store the files in the DB and pull the files from it depending on the required languages for the given operation, kind of like a local cache. The cache should maintain a relatively small sizes, regularly cleaning the rarely used languages. Another one is similar to what you've said.

Comment: Yea, I was considering suggesting a database, but I wasn't sure the cost/benefit was there in terms of dev time to implement. Then again, neither solution seems exactly straightforward, but yea those are the only two solutions I could see, and just decided not to mention the database and I wasn't sure it was actual possible/practical. The API is definitely an approach that could be done, so I used that.